# JQuery .each loop prob

Tags: php, jquery, html

Okay so here's the idea:

I want to make a jQuery script to handle multiple forms. Every form has a button. When you click this button the script should send all input fields' name and value in $_POST to the form's action URL. But I can't make it work.

It won't loop through my .each on line 3 in my jQuery file.

jQuery:

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
    var query = {};
    $(this).parent('form').children('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        query[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });

    $.post($(this).parent('form').attr('action'), query, function(data) {
        $("#dialog").html(data);
        $("#ui-id-1").html('Activate account');
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }, 'json');
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/action/activateacc.php">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>E-mail:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" /></td>
        <td><img class="tick" id="mailIMG" width="20px" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Activation code:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="code" name="code" /></td>
        <td><img class="tick" id="codeIMG" width="20px" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Choose organization-name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
        <td><img class="tick" id="nameIMG" width="20px" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><input type="button" style="cursor:pointer" value="Activate account" /></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) with the form to get name/values of your inputs- also you should be using closest since parent only goes up one level

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){   
    var query = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
    $.post($(this).parent('form').attr('action'), query , function(data) {
        $("#dialog").html(data);
        $("#ui-id-1").html('Activate account');
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }, 'json');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.parent()` only goes up a single level of the DOM - try using `.closest()` and `find()` - so

```
$(this).closets('form').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find` to find children and `.parents` to find the form

```
$(this).parents('form').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        query[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way for me to read it, would be to use `.closest()` (which goes up all the way instead of parent which is one level) and also `find()` (which runs a query through your current jQuery object):

```
$(this).closest('form').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(){ 
    query[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/86U5g/)**

Answer (score 0):

`parent()` only goes up 1 level in the DOM tree and `children()` only goes down 1 level in the DOM tree.

You should try either to use more of them if you are 100% sure the structure won't change (not recommended, it's not that clean), or use `closest()`, that will retrieve the closest given tag name in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can spare yourself from the headaches of serializing your `form` elements into a query by simply using the built-in [`$.serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form
>   elements.

In your case:

```
var query = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
```